# PHP - exit(0) inside headers_sent()?

Tags: php, if-statement, http-headers, exit

So I have this code:

```
<?php
// Set headers
if (!headers_sent()) {
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    header('Content-Style-Type: text/css');
    header('Content-Script-Type: application/javascript');
    header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
    header('Content-language: en-US');
    header('X-Powered-By: ');
    header_remove('X-Powered-By');
    header('Last-Modified: Tue, 01 Jan 2013 00:00:00 GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
    header('Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2013 00:00:00 GMT');
    exit(0);
}
```

After I added `exit(0);` my page appeared completely blank. No HTML. Any ideas why? Should I even use `exit(0);`? It is used on 1 of the examples on [php.net](http://php.net//manual/bg/function.headers-sent.php). Also if I remove `exit(0)` the whole page looks alright.

Comment: exit() exits, so youŕe just sending headers

Comment: So you mean I shouldn't use it?

Comment: you should use when it is ok to exit (probably not just after headers sent).

Comment: Maybe in the end of the script file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you cite is using `exit;` in order to cease execution of the page, because the page is being redirected via headers. You don't want to do that unless you want to *stop running the page*.

Generally, you don't need `exit;`, except to stop your page prematurely. Incidentally, the `headers_sent()` call isn't really directly related here.

Comment: OK after 6 minutes expire I'll accept this answer. Also you mean `headers_sent()` shouldn't use `exit(0);` if there is more code bellow it. I've just put it under my `</html>` tag.

Comment: @PowerUser You don't need to use `exit` at all.

Comment: @PowerUser It really has nothing to do with `headers_sent()`. That's just incidental to the task being done there. And also, `headers_sent()` is not "using" it at all. Finally, correct; you should not use `exit;` if you have code below that you intend to execute.